VueJs Chrome Extension - Vite server did not start
We have set up a Chrome extension using vueJs using hmr. We are facing an issue on the development server to run the extension on windows 11.
Webpage Render:
Vite server did not start

Configuration:
Windows 11 12th gen i7 processor
vite: ^3.1.6
vue: ^3.2.40
Node: v20

vite.config.ts:
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { dirname, relative } from 'path'
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import Icons from 'unplugin-icons/vite'
import IconsResolver from 'unplugin-icons/resolver'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import UnoCSS from 'unocss/vite'
import { isDev, port, r } from './scripts/utils'
import { MV3Hmr } from './vite-mv3-hmr'
export const sharedConfig: UserConfig = {
  root: r('src'),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~/': `${r('src')}/`,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    
    [Vue()],
    AutoImport({
      imports: [
        'vue',
        {
          'webextension-polyfill': [
            ['*', 'browser'],
          ],
        },
      ],
      dts: r('src/auto-imports.d.ts'),
    }),
    Components({
      dirs: [r('src/components')],
      // generate `components.d.ts` for ts support with Volar
      dts: r('src/components.d.ts'),
      resolvers: [
        // auto import icons
        IconsResolver({
          componentPrefix: '',
        }),
      ],
    }),
    Icons(),
    UnoCSS(),
    replace({
      '__DEV__': JSON.stringify(isDev),
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(isDev ? 'development' : 'production'),
      '__VUE_OPTIONS_API__': JSON.stringify(true),
      '__VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__': JSON.stringify(false),
    }),

    // rewrite assets to use relative path
    {
      name: 'assets-rewrite',
      enforce: 'post',
      apply: 'build',
      transformIndexHtml(html, { path }) {
        return html.replace(/"\/assets\//g, `"${relative(dirname(path), '/assets')}/`)
      },
    },
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      'vue',
      '@vueuse/core',
      'webextension-polyfill',
    ],
    exclude: [
      'vue-demi',
    ],
  },
}

export default defineConfig(({ command }) => ({
  ...sharedConfig,
  base: command === 'serve' ? `http://localhost:${port}/` : './extension/dist',
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    port,
    hmr: {
      host: `http://localhost:${port}/`,
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: r('extension/dist'),
    emptyOutDir: false,
    sourcemap: isDev ? 'inline' : false,
    terserOptions: {
      mangle: false,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        options: r('src/options/index.html'),
        popup: r('src/popup/index.html'),
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    ...sharedConfig.plugins!,

    MV3Hmr(),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
}))

script to run dev server:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run clear && cross-env NODE_ENV=development run-p dev:*",
    "dev:prepare": "esno scripts/prepare.ts",
    "dev:web": "vite dev",
    "dev:js": "npm run build:js -- --mode development",
    "dev:bg": "tsup --watch ./src",
  }

Your help can save someone's career :D

Did you started the dev server?

Yes, I will add the script as well (if needed). Its working fine on production mode

Assuming you're using NPM, you could run npm run dev and everything should work well. Otherwise, you can always launch all of them independently web, js etc...

@kissu I have updated the question with scripts. Also doing the same as you suggested

So what happens when you follow my previous comment?

The issue is the same.

If you run them one by one independently it gives the same error? Any errors in the terminal?

No. error, the Extension got installed successfully when trying to open it shows the Vite server did not start on the browser. It is working fine as well on MacOS
